# Is it a correct sentence? "Experience vacation in the city and at the beach"

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know whether it is a correct sentence or not.

> Experience vacation in the city and at the beach.

Answer (score -1):

It needs an indefinite article or possessive pronoun in front of vacation.  Something like a or your.